# localhost on OS X Mavericks cannot connect

Tags: localhost, osx-mavericks

I just upgraded to OS X Mavericks and whenever I try to go to localhost/~username/ in any browser I get a 'could not connect' error. Has something changed that I should know about? I use localhost all the time to preview sites I'm working on.

Comment: thanks to whoever voted this down! updated my OS and something stopped working, seemed like a legit question to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [apache](http://brianflove.com/2013/10/23/os-x-mavericks-and-apache/) server isn't running by default anymore, start it and then localhost should work.

Comment: says apache is already running, when i sudo apachectl -t I get the following error: 'Invalid command 'PerlHandler', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration'

Comment: Check this link - https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083 - it appears relevant to your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the response in this post in order to get the permissions I needed to edit that file: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=424115